# error in select query

Tags: php, db2

I am using an as400 db2 iseries and I can't fetch the data from database.  If I use for loop its working fine, but when I use while loop am getting error.
Here i update the code for your reference...

Code:

```
$database = 'xxxxxx';
$user = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$hostname = 'x.x.x.x';

 include('adodb.inc.php');

     $db = ADONewConnection('odbc');
     $dsn = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$hostname;DATABASE=$database;";
     if($db->Connect($dsn,$user,$password)){
         $query = "SELECT * FROM IND0301F.XMAGLF0 WHERE XMCDMA='I01' AND XMCDUB=''"; 
         $res = odbc_exec($query); 
         while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) { 
             echo $row['XMARCD'];  exit;
          } 
     }


<?php // no direct access 
  //defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<?php
 set_time_limit(0); 
  //echo "Current User is ". $uname=$_SESSION['username']; 
?>
<?php
$database = 'IND0301F';
$user = 'QUSER';
$password = 'QUSER';
$hostname = '10.10.0.30';
?>



<?php
     include('adodb.inc.php');

     $db = ADONewConnection('odbc');
     $dsn = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=$hostname;DATABASE=$database;";
     if($db->Connect($dsn,$user,$password)){
         $sql_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IND0301F.XMAGLF0 WHERE XMCDMA='I01' AND XMCDUB=''"; 
         $rs_count = $db->Execute($sql_count);
         $result_count = $rs_count->GetArray();
         $count_rd = $result_count[0][0];  
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM IND0301F.XMAGLF0 WHERE XMCDMA='I01' AND XMCDUB=''";
         $rs = $db->Execute($sql);
         if (!$rs) echo "<p>no records</p>";
         else 
             {
             $result = $rs->GetArray();
?>


<tr>
<th>VRVCODE</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>UOM</th>
<th>WH</th>
<th>Stock </th>
<th>Material Requested but PO not placed</th>
<th>Ordered</th>
<th>Items expected to deliver in 1 month</th>
<th>Items expected to deliver in 2 month</th>
<th>Items expected to deliver in 3 month</th>
<th>Items expected to deliver in morethan 3  month</th>
</tr>


<?php 
            for($i=0;$i<$count_rd;$i++)
            { ?>          
                <tr  class="odd_gradeX">     
<?php
                    for($j=0;$j<=53;$j++)
                        {  // 0 3 4 7 9 17 18 19 20 21 22 
                         if(($j != 1) && ($j != 2) && ($j != 10) &&  ($j != 5) && ($j != 6) && ($j != 8) && ($j != 11) && ($j != 12) 
                          && ($j != 13) &&  ($j != 14) && ($j != 15) && ($j != 16)
                          && ($j != 23) &&  ($j != 24) && ($j != 25) && ($j != 26) && ($j != 27)
                          && ($j != 28) && ($j != 29) 
                          && ($j != 30) &&  ($j != 36) && ($j != 37) && ($j != 38) && ($j != 39)
                          && ($j != 31) && ($j != 32)  && ($j != 33) && ($j != 34) && ($j != 35)&& ($j != 40) && ($j != 41) && ($j != 42) && ($j != 43) && ($j != 44) && ($j != 45) && ($j != 46) && ($j != 47) && ($j != 48) && ($j != 49) && ($j != 50) && ($j != 51) && ($j != 52) && ($j != 53)){
                        ?>
                        <?php 
                        if(($j == 9)||($j == 17)||($j == 18) ||($j == 19) ||($j == 20) ||($j == 21) ||($j == 22)){ ?>
                        <td align="right">
                        <?php }  elseif(($j == 3)){ ?>
                  <td align="left"> <?php }
                           else { ?> 
                  <td align="center"> <?php } ?> 
                           <?php  
                             if($result[$i][$j]!='') 
                             { 
                             ?>   <?php 
                             echo $result[$i][$j];  ?> <?php   
                             echo "&nbsp;";              
                             } }
                              ?>
                  </td>
                    <?php } ?>
          </tr><?php
            }  ?>



<?php
           }
     } else {
         echo "Not working";
         echo 'SQLSTATE: '.$db->ErrorNo()."<br>";
         echo 'Message: '.$db->ErrorMsg()."<br><br>";
     } 
?>
```

Comment: You are getting an error? Do we need to guess what error or are you able to add it to your question?

Comment: no we just add the data's through as400 itself.. not programmmatic... inserting data manually..

Comment: You should focus on ADO only functions when you use ADODB. Mixing will ohter functions from ohter libraries (as you do in your example) can only lead to unexpected behaviour and errors (which you hide, too)

Comment: hi hakre, i just update my code, i used for loop, if i use for loop its working fine, but i don't know how to fetch the result through while loop.. can you help me?

Comment: The problem remains. You should either use ADODB or the PHP odbc extension. But both mixed is akward (and useless).